# Hibernate Envers Track changes of referenced Classes

Tags: hibernate, grails, hibernate-envers

I have an Class `Foo`

```
@Audited
class Foo {
   Bar bar
   static hasMany = [worlds:World]
}    
@Audited
class Bar {
   String bla
}   
@Audited
class World {
   String hello
}
```

So If something changes in 'Bar' or 'World' i would like to make an new Log Entry for Foo.

How can I configure hibernate envers that if any referenced Class is changed that an log entry is also generated for the Class that used the changed class?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a configuration toggle for that.

If Envers detects that the changes made only affect a `Bar` instance or a `World` instance and those changes are not directly impacting the state of `Foo`, then `Foo` won't be audited.

In order to include `Foo` as a part of those changes, you'd need to explicitly change an audited attribute on the parent `Foo` entity so that its state was different, and thus a revision generated.